# How to render Html tags passed as string property in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to pass HTML tags as properties and then render in React.js

For example ES2015 syntax:

I add the property as a string with HTML tags:

```
renderItems(posts) {
    var groupDate = this.props.item.date.toUpperCase();
    var listCol = '<h4>' + groupDate.toString() + '</h4>';
    return (<ViewList list={posts} postCol1={listCol}/>);
}
```

And in my ViewList component I have:

```
<div className="col-md-9">{this.props.postCol1}</div>
```

This is rendered as :

```
<h4>JANUARY 28TH, 2016</h4>
```

How do I get react to render the date excluding the HTML tags?

Different views uses this component and tags may be different explaining why I would like to include the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `<h4>` tags out of the `listCol` string. Your `ViewList` component should render them:

```
<div className="col-md-9">
    <h4>
        {this.props.postCol1}
    </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Different views uses this component and tags may be different explaining why I would like to include the tag.

Comment: Make it a div, and give it a different class according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked:

```
renderItems(posts) {
     var groupDate = this.props.item.date.toUpperCase();
     return (<ViewList list={posts} postCol1={<h4>{groupDate.toString()}</h4>}/>);
   }
```